# "Cars of Grab" or "Grab cars"

Tags: possessives

What is the difference between two phrases "Cars of Grab" and "Grab cars"? I used "Cars of Grab" phrase for the subject of the sentence but a native speaker suggested using "Grab cars" instead.

Note: Grab in the phrase is a company which does business in the transportation service.

Comment: Look around, there are many *Ola Cabs*!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Grab', being a company (or essentially, a 'brand'), becomes an attributive noun when used to modify 'cars'. So, 'Grab cars' refers to the cars that provide the transportation services of the company, 'Grab' (context-based, we know that the company 'Grab' provides transportation services).

'Cars of Grab', on the other hand, shows ownership.